# What is the best way to make background waves in an html page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I want to know about the best way to use wavy svg images in html webpage that are also responsive with screen size without using media queries.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmXiz.jpg)

also this is the approach i am trying currently

```
background: url("/images/background_svg/heading.svg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
```

but this image is not responsive also this is the code of svg image

```
<svg width="1440" height="212" viewBox="0 0 1440 212" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M0 50C0 22.3858 22.3858 0 50 0H1398C1425.61 0 1448 22.3858 1448 50V168C1448 168 1368.5 266.5 724 168C79.5 69.5 0 168 0 168V50Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
<defs>
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="724" y1="2.72102e-06" x2="743.131" y2="211.306" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#114ED1"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#2168FF"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: See https://css-doodle.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are websites that can help you create waves as a background, they give you several options on how to create waves.

You just need to enter the website, see how you want your waves to be created, and they will give you HTML and CSS code to add to your document, and it is responsive!
In the example below I created the div *wave*, it will simply fill 100% of the page with `skyblue` color and will center all elements in the center. You don't really need it, don't worry about it.

You can just ignore the div *wave*, and if you want to add color to the element's background, use `body { background-color: your_color;}`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Waves</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .custom-shape-divider-bottom-1608219034 {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            line-height: 0;
            transform: rotate(180deg);
        }

        .custom-shape-divider-bottom-1608219034 svg {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            width: calc(100% + 1.3px);
            height: 150px;
        }

        .custom-shape-divider-bottom-1608219034 .shape-fill {
            fill: #000000;
        }

        .wave {
            background-color: skyblue;
            /* position: relative; */
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            flex-direction: row;
        }
        .wave .box h1 {
            color: white;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wave">
        <div class="box">
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-shape-divider-bottom-1608219034">
            <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120"
                preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <path
                    d="M0,0V46.29c47.79,22.2,103.59,32.17,158,28,70.36-5.37,136.33-33.31,206.8-37.5C438.64,32.43,512.34,53.67,583,72.05c69.27,18,138.3,24.88,209.4,13.08,36.15-6,69.85-17.84,104.45-29.34C989.49,25,1113-14.29,1200,52.47V0Z"
                    opacity=".25" class="shape-fill"></path>
                <path
                    d="M0,0V15.81C13,36.92,27.64,56.86,47.69,72.05,99.41,111.27,165,111,224.58,91.58c31.15-10.15,60.09-26.07,89.67-39.8,40.92-19,84.73-46,130.83-49.67,36.26-2.85,70.9,9.42,98.6,31.56,31.77,25.39,62.32,62,103.63,73,40.44,10.79,81.35-6.69,119.13-24.28s75.16-39,116.92-43.05c59.73-5.85,113.28,22.88,168.9,38.84,30.2,8.66,59,6.17,87.09-7.5,22.43-10.89,48-26.93,60.65-49.24V0Z"
                    opacity=".5" class="shape-fill"></path>
                <path
                    d="M0,0V5.63C149.93,59,314.09,71.32,475.83,42.57c43-7.64,84.23-20.12,127.61-26.46,59-8.63,112.48,12.24,165.56,35.4C827.93,77.22,886,95.24,951.2,90c86.53-7,172.46-45.71,248.8-84.81V0Z"
                    class="shape-fill"></path>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Websites you can use to make waves:

https://www.shapedivider.app/ (Used in the code above)
 https://getwaves.io/